# Set Footer Only On Last Page - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, printing, footer

I want to Set the footer only on last page for printing , i need the footer just to appear on the last page,

here is my code

```
     <style> 
          @media print {   #content:after {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            margin-bottom: 594mm; 
             } 
           }  
        </style>
        <table>   
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>PAGE HEADER</th>
            </tr>   </thead>   <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>PAGE FOOTER</td>
            </tr>   </tfoot>   <tbody>
            <tr>        
            <td id="content">           

    Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>             Content</br> Content</br>  Content</br>Content</br>         
</td>
    </tr>   
     </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: This problem is about server-side scripting (unless you are using SPA's or whatsoever). What server-side language are you using? PHP? ASP? You should check out those topics. Not even mentioning static html pages If you are creating all pages one by one you could do it with simply not adding the foother on the page you'd like.

Comment: am using php i searched and i didnt found , its dynamically . i will explain for you its an invoice page , it depends on how many lines are in the page , if its two pages i need the footer to be only on the last page , if the lines are just on one page so the footer will be only on the first page